# Wrong ip when setting up Redis cluster on Kubernetes "Waiting for the cluster to join..."

Tags: docker, redis, kubernetes, redis-cluster

I am trying to build a redis cluster with kubernetes on azure. And I am faced with the exact same problem when running different samples : [sanderp.nl/running-redis-cluster-on-kubernetes](https://sanderp.nl/running-redis-cluster-on-kubernetes-e451bda76cad) or [github.com/zuxqoj/kubernetes-redis-cluster](https://github.com/zuxqoj/kubernetes-redis-cluster/blob/master/README-using-statefulset.md)

Everything goes well until I try to have the different nodes join the cluster with the `redis-trib` command.
At that time I face the infamous infinite "**Waiting for the cluster to join ....**" message.

Trying to see what is happening, I set up the loglevel of the redis pods to `debug` level. I then noticed that the pods do not seem to announce their correct ip when communicating together.
In fact it seems that the **last byte of the ip is replaced by a zero**. Say if pod1 has ip address 10.1.34.**9**, I will see in pod2 logs:

Accepted clusternode 10.1.34.**0**:*someport*

So the pods do  not seem to be able to communicate back and the join cluster process never ends.

Now, if before running redis-trib, **I enforce the cluster-announce-ip** by running on each pod :

```
redis-cli -h mypod-ip config set cluster-announce-ip mypod-ip
```

**the redis-trib command then completes successfully** and the cluster is up and running.

But this not a viable solution as if a pod goes down and comes back, it may have changed ip and I will face the same problem when it will try to join the cluster.

Note that I do not encounter any problem when running the samples with minikube.

I am using flannel for kubernetes networking. Can the problem come from incorrect configuration of flannel ? Has anyone encountered the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [statefulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for deploying your replicas, so your pod will have a unique name always.

Moreover, you will be able to use `service` DNS-names as host. See this official doc [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

The second example you shared, has another part for [redis cluster using statefulsets](https://github.com/zuxqoj/kubernetes-redis-cluster/blob/master/README-using-statefulset.md). Try that out.

Comment: I already tried the statefulset sample. It does not make any difference as redis cluster internal mechanics is about ips, not names.